# Apply base style of window to inherited window

Tags: wpf

I have defined a style for the Window class in my ResourceDictionary:

```
    <Style x:Key="windowStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Width="300" Height="300" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want a specialized window. To this end I inherit a new class from Window and add custom DependecyProperties etc.
My goal is to reuse the base style, ie. I pretty much only want to fill the ContentPresenter from the base style with a grid and add a new ContentPresenter in one of its cells, so I tried this:

```
    <Style x:Key="customWindowStyle" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource windowStyle}" 
           TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Which gives me an exception at runtime, since the ContentTemplate is of type DataTemplate as opposed to ControlTemplate. Of course if I Set the Template instead of ContentTemplate in the customWindowStyle, I lose the style of the base window.

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do therefore I don't think this will solve your *real* problem, but when you want to assign somethiong to the ContentPresenter inside the ControlTemnplate of a ContentControl, then simply set the Content property of the templated control. Either bind to the Window.Content property or simply add the content between the <Window></Window>  tags. In case of a Style set the Window.Content using a Setter.

Comment: The ContentPresenter inside a ContentControl binds implicitly to the ContentControl.Content property (if the ContentPresenter.Content property is not explicitly set).

Comment: What I want to have is a specialized window which uses the same style as the base window, but with additional content (for example, a button bar at the bottom).

Comment: For the additional content, you would have to override the ControlTemplate of the base style.